# Stripe response page php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

In Stripe I created a payment link, you can add a response link or redirect link. Now what I want to do is on the redirect link (page) get the response of whether the payment was a success and for which product it was so I can store some data in wordpress database.

I searched the stripe API, but could not find a suiteable solution.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can [add `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` to your Payment Link's redirect URL](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#change-confirmation-behavior).  It will be replaced with the Checkout Session ID after the redirect, and then you can use it to [retrieve the Checkout Session from the Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and determine the status of the payment, what was purchased, and so on.

```
https://example.com/return/url/?session={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}
```